# Получить переменную в сервис и сделать проверку

Tags: java, android, eclipse

На eclipse android перешел недавно. ((

В чем проблема?

```
public void onCreate() {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        int latValue = extras.getInt("LatValue"); //получаю значение в переменную 
        if(latValue==1){ 
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample1); //делаю проверку 
        }
        if(latValue==2){
        mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample); //делаю проверку 
        }
        mPlayer.setLooping(false);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Вопрос не ясен. Чего вы ожидали и что получили?

2) Вместо 2-х "if" сделайте так:

```
if(latValue==1)
{
//yuors code
mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample); //делаю проверку 
mPlayer.setLooping(false);
}
else if(latValue==2)
{
//yours code
mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sample1); //делаю проверку 
mPlayer.setLooping(false);
}
else
{
// не 2 и не 1
}

//если вызвать это тут, можете нарваться на NullPointerException, если latValue
// не 1 и не 2
//mPlayer.setLooping(false);
```

3) И код этот поместите лучше в

```
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
```

куда intent уже подан.

Соответственно доставать переменную надо так будет:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
int latValue = extras.getInt("LatValue"); //получаю значение в переменную
```